# how to get year from datestring with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a td element in which is a date:

```
<td class="date-table">2021-09-02</td>
```

How can i get the year from that string?

Below does not work

```
var date = $(.date-table').text(); // read text inside td
var d = new Date(date);
var year = d.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Youre missing a `'` in your first line of js. It should be `var date = $('.date-table').text();`. Once thats done your code just runs fine.

Comment: You can also just slice the year off if the strings will always be in the same format `var year = date.slice(0, 4);` (voting to close as typo)

Comment: you should use a ide that shows you hints like this. even after posting it here, you should recognize the highlighted code by missing `'`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem**. "does not work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Answer (score 1):

Missing a opening quote in your first line of js.

(I also added proper table markup around your tr and an alert for showing the years value for the sake of completeness).

```js
var date = $('.date-table').text(); // read text inside td
var d = new Date(date);
var year = d.getFullYear();
console.log(year);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="date-table">2021-09-02</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Agree. Stupid typo. thanks for attention

Comment: _"Missing a opening quote..."_ - Is something that should be closed as typo. An answer doesn't provide anything useful for future readers.

Comment: @Andreas i was actually searching the flags for that point to mark it as that, didnt find the proper flag tho, what would i choose as a flag in that case?

Comment: _"A community-specific reason" -> "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"_